# My launchd scripts are not run after boot but after login

Tags: launchd, plist

I want to start a shell script when a MacOS (14.2.1) machine boots. But the scripts is executed only when I log in, not directly after the system has started.

I wrote a plist definition like this:

```
> ls -l /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.foobar.justLog.plist
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  wheel  397 Jan 25 21:06 /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.foobar.justLog.plist
> cat /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.foobar.justLog.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.foobar.justLog</string>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/justLog.sh</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
>
```

The referenced shell script looks like this:

```
> ls -l /usr/local/bin/justLog.sh
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  105 Jan 25 14:46 /usr/local/bin/justLog.sh
> cat /usr/local/bin/justLog.sh
#!/bin/bash
while true ;do
    echo "Started script $0 as user $(whoami) in $PWD ($(date))"
    sleep 120
done
>
```

Then I shutdown the mac, waited 2 minutes and turned on the mac (from 21:46:40 to 21:46:55). Then I waited a minute to give the scripts some time. Then I logged on with my default user (from 21:48:00 to 21:48:36). Afterwards I check the files in /var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd and I see that there are no entries from launchd in minutes 21:46, 21:47. But thats exactly the time where the system boots. Only for the minute where I logged in I find entries from launchd. It looks like launchd does nothing before the first user logs in.

```
> for i in 5 6 7 8 ;do echo "inspecting minute: 21:4$i"; grep "2024-01-25 21:4${i}:" /var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd/launchd.log{.2,.1,} /var/log/* 2>/dev/null | wc -l ;done
inspecting minute: 21:45
   11747
inspecting minute: 21:46
       0
inspecting minute: 21:47
       0
inspecting minute: 21:48
   21150
>
```

Can anyone explain why my script is not executed before I log in?

Comment: Aside: it's often useful to use `say` or `afplay` a bong sound when debugging scripts to know when something happens.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110336/launchd-wont-load-plists-at-boot

Comment: @Tetsujin I think I did not make the same mistakes as as described in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110336/launchd-wont-load-plists-at-boot . As you see in my description: my plist is in /Library/LaunchDaemons. Must be something different here

Comment: what puzzles me with my setup: I looks like launchd and a lot of the boot process seem to happen only when I login. When I reboot, wait 2 minutes and then login I see entries in /var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd/launchd.log which all are dated with a timestamp which is shortly after I entered my password during login:

Comment: I found out the reason for this problem (sadly no solution was found):

Comment: The problem was that the the mac was using FileVault to encrypt the whole disk (I wasn't aware about that). Therefore the launch daemons which definitions are persisted of course in  the file system can only start once the disk gets decrypted. And this only happens when a user types in his password on the login screen.
Up to now I couldn't find a solution. If you have a FileVault encrypted disk you cannot access the disk content and therefore no daemons can start unless a user logs in the disk is decrypted.